# How to terminate a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I am Using javascript to build a colouring tool with four colours.
I first draw with green but when I click on the button red it keeps colouring in green.
Each colour is connected to a button and that button calls different javascript files
Can someone help me figure out how to end one script to start calling another one

I looked online but I couldn't find anything helpful.

The functions are working just fine.

Here is the code that is calling the javascript file once a button is clicked.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('green');
var loaded = false;
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if(loaded) return;
    loaded = true;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'green.js';
    var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        script.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            // now you can access the functions inside the JS file
        });
    } else {
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") {
                // access the functions in the JS file
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you include both files on your website and then call the other scripts functions instead of using this weird script loading?

Comment: `return false;` can be used to exit from function.

Comment: return false; didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Code looks complex and asks for questions like this :).

Maybe you should connect the script file to the button (button.script = ...)
Then put the `first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first)` above the:

```
if(loaded) return;
```

line.

Answer (score 0):

In order to exit from a function you just can do: `return false;`